# Can't install matlab 2011a on Yosemite

Tags: install, macos

I cannot install matlab 2011a student on yosemite. I click on the OSX installer, a matlab screen pops up then goes away.

Has anyone install 2011a on OSX Yosemite ?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. MALAB R2014b is the only version that **officially** supports Yosemite. That said, I do have seen several workarounds that enable you to temporarily use the older-version MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

I post Gigon Bae recommendation from Mac website!
I tried with Yosemite and Matlab 2011b and it worked!

Aug 20, 2014 6:39 AM

I was trying to install MATLAB R2013a on my macbook (OSX 10.9) and had the same problem.

I finally found a solution without uninstall other versions of java from oracle.

1. double-click .dmg file (installer)
2. copy all files in the dmg file into a folder.
3. run Terminal and go to the folder. and type 'chmod +w install'
4. type 'vi install'  (edit 'install' text file)
5. find the following text
           # Ask for a 64-bit Java 1.6 (or higher) VM
           DEFAULT_JRE_LOC=`$JAVA_HOME_CMD -v 1.6* -d64 -F`
6. change '1.6+' to '1.6*'  (specifying a lower version[jdk se6] of java which would be Apple Java SE 6.
7. save the file (install)
8. run 'install' file by double-clicking

If Apple Java SE 6 is not installed, please visit http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572  (be sure you installed this)

Hope this helps.